# How to invert a grep expression

Tags: regex, linux, grep

The following grep expression successfully lists all the .exe and .html files in the current directory and sub directories.

```
ls -R |grep -E .*[\.exe]$\|.*[\.html]$
```

How do I invert this result to list those that aren't a .html or .exe instead. (That is, `!=`.)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

Use command-line option `-v` or `--invert-match`,

```
ls -R |grep -v -E .*[\.exe]$\|.*[\.html]$
```

Comment: It should be noted that `-v`/`--invert-match` will not necessarily flip whether the return code of `grep` indicates successful execution, but will instead match the lines which would otherwise not be matched. Those who are looking to invert the return code (i.e. succeed if all of the lines do not match the pattern, rather than at least one) should use `! grep`. This finds use in conditional expressions, e.g.: `if ! ls | grep -qE ".(\.exe)$"; then echo No .exe files in $(pwd); fi`.

Comment: I could not get the above to work, but this worked for me: `ls -R | grep -v -E ".*(\.exe)$|.*(\.vue)$"`

Answer (score 130):

```
grep -v
```

or

```
grep --invert-match
```

You can also do the same thing using `find`:

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*" ! -iname ".exe" ! -iname ".html"\)
```

More info [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-command-exclude-ignore-files/).

Comment: The `find` command is the most semantic solution to this XY problem. Combining `ls` and `grep` for this purpose seems hacky at best. This should be the accepted answer. (+1)

Comment: @Eric Regardless of the OP's requirements, inverting a grep expression is useful for much more than finding files. I doubt that's the reason most people come here.

Answer (score 37):

Add the `-v` option to your `grep` command to invert the results.

Answer (score 26):

As stated multiple times, inversion is achieved by the `-v` option to `grep`. Let me add the (hopefully amusing) note that you could have figured this out yourself by grepping through the `grep` help text:

```
grep --help | grep invert
```

> -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines

Answer (score 16):

```
 grep "subscription" | grep -v "spec"
```