# Exclude certain matches in grep

Tags: php, grep

Say I'm auditing a CMS for SQL injection, I'd run something like

```
grep -r "\$_GET" index.php
```

However, usually that would return outputs with things such as intval($_GET['id']);

What command would I run to take out matches that have "intval" in them?

Comment: The only relevant tag here is `grep`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to invert a grep expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373675/how-to-invert-a-grep-expression)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep --invert-match` or simply `grep -v` like this:

```
grep -r "\$_GET" index.php | grep -v intval
```

The first `grep` call finds all the matches, the second removes the ones you didn't want.