# GREP - Exclude line entries that have a question mark "?"

Tags: awk, grep

I have a large file with over 800k entries (access log file). I need to output a file with only clean URLs (without parameters / "?") in the URL.

Output should only display entries that DON'T have a "?" in the URL.

Parameter url:

http://www.example.com/sample?parameter=1

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373675/how-to-invert-a-grep-expression

Comment: Excellent closing guys. Have any of you actually tried a regex with a question mark in grep?

Answer (score 5):

In `POSIX` `grep` with the `--invert-match` (short: `-v`) for inverse match,

```
grep --invert-match "?" file
```

Or using `awk` with `!`

```
awk '!/?/' file
```

Using `GNU sed` with `--quiet` or `--silent` (short: `-n`):

```
sed --quiet '/?/!p' file
```

Comment: There's nothing GNU specific about grep -v.

Answer (score 3):

@Seasonal_showers: You haven't shown us a handful samples, so considering that your Input_file will have only URLs and nothing else, could you please try following then.

```
grep -v '?' Input_file
```

Let me know if this is not helping, you could show more sample Input_file details for better understanding then.