# How can I delete a specific text in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a text file :

```
192.168.47.100 computer
192.168.47.101 phone
192.168.47.1 computer3
192.168.47.50 computer2
```

and I want to delete `192.168.47.1` line

I tried

```
while read line
do
    IPTemp="$line"
    ex -s +"g/$IPTemp/d" -cwq $1
done < IPLib.txt
```

but output is :

```
192.168.47.50 computer 3
```

I tried `sed 's/192.168.47.1//g'` but again output is :

```
00 computer
01 phone
computer3
192.168.47.50 computer2
```

I searched on google but but I am not able to find the right one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invert a grep expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373675/how-to-invert-a-grep-expression)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern matches 3 lines in your data. You need to end it with `$`. Also, if you use `sed`'s replace (`s/`) you end up with empty lines. Use delete:

```
$ sed '/192\.168\.47\.1$/d' file
192.168.47.100
192.168.47.101
192.168.47.50
```

In awk:

```
$ awk '!/192\.168\.47\.1$/' file
192.168.47.100
192.168.47.101
192.168.47.50
```

another in awk where the whole first column is compared to a string, not using regex (thanks @Kent for pointing out):

```
$ awk '$1!="192.168.47.1"' file
192.168.47.100
192.168.47.101
192.168.47.50
```

and using `grep`:

```
$ grep -v 192\.168\.47\.1$ file
192.168.47.100
192.168.47.101
192.168.47.50
```

**Edit:** Apparently you changed the data. Now you need to end the pattern with a space:

```
$ sed '/192\.168\.47\.1 /d' file2
192.168.47.100 computer
192.168.47.101 phone
192.168.47.50 computer2
```

and in awk:

```
$ awk '!/192\.168\.47\.1 /' file2
192.168.47.100 computer
192.168.47.101 phone
192.168.47.50 computer2
```

and `grep`:

```
$ grep -v 192\.168\.47\.1\  file2
192.168.47.100 computer
192.168.47.101 phone
192.168.47.50 computer2
```

Comment: since you have used awk, why not directly making use of `$1` instead of appending a space in regex?

Comment: @Kent The data  changed from one to two columns while writing these. Not just there, yet.

Comment: `.` is meta character... suggest to keep only `awk '$1 != "192.168.47.1"'` and `grep -vF '192.168.47.1 '` and delete the rest or escape each `.`

Comment: @Sundeep You are right. D**n that'll be a lot of \ing... Thanks anyway. Well, for the community...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with sed. You just need to force force an exact match with `<>`
So:

```
sed 's/\<192\.168\.47\.1\>/d'
```

should work.

Comment: Wow, didn't know they had a special meaning. Is it the same as `^` and `$`?

Comment: Yep, it is some sort of anchor like ^ and $.

Comment: they are beginning and ending word boundaries... but likely specific to GNU sed only(https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions) ... the `.` is meta character and so has to be escaped to match literally.. and the question is about deleting the line, not just the matched string

Comment: Thanks for the constructive input. Now it should be right.

Answer (score -1):

To remove the line and print the output to standard out:

`sed '/192.168.47.1/d' ./infile`

To directly modify the file (and create a backup):

`sed -i.bak '/192.168.47.1/d' ./infile`

Comment: This has the same problem as the OP's attempt. It will match other IP addresses, too.